# Write User Authentication from Scratch or use a Gem - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts and opinions on what you prefer and why? If you were planning on writing a user authentication system for your ruby on rails website would you write from bottom to top or would you be using a gem like authlogic, devise, restful_ authentication etc etc etc?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you know what you're doing and just need the functionality, why reinvent the wheel? I have used [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) a lot and think it is a perfect standard authentication system.

However, if you are either still learning Rails or only getting to know the principles of authentication systems, it is probably best to first build one yourself from scratch. As it says in [devise's documentation](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br):

> If you are building your first Rails application, we recommend you to not use Devise. Devise requires a good understanding of the Rails Framework. In such cases, we advise you to start a simple authentication system from scratch, today we have two resources:
>
> Michael Hartl's online book: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top
> Ryan Bates' Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
>
> Once you have solidified your understanding of Rails and authentication mechanisms, we assure you Devise will be very pleasant to work with. :)

Comment: hmm, I guess I'm a little lazy bothering and actually write the complete user authentication from scratch, at least not yet. I feel like I first want to get the function going and then later on I'll check weather I want to write the whole complete shit from the ground. 
I was actually considering Authlogic, but then I wasn't able to really make it function properly - because I'm a nooby rookie little dog. I'm giving Sorcery a try now though. Thanks! ;)

Comment: No problem! Even though this is a question that cannot really be answered but rather be discussed, please checkmark the answer that helped you most.

Comment: but you both helped me... I can't choose, therefore I won't check none of you. Or can I check both of you?
-------------------------------------
Also, away from the above text. I tried Sorcery and I've tried Authlogic and I'm still in doubt weather to make the user authentication from scratch. Take twitter from example, they use OAuth, is that even a gem?

Comment: Yes - Google is your friend: https://github.com/pelle/oauth

Comment: I don't care about OAuth, I was only wondering, if you were the Twitter developer would you make the authentication from scratch or use a gem?

Comment: What do you think of Doorkeeper OAuth 2?

Comment: Also one thing which got me pondering. Do you think the makers of OAuth are able to hack Twitter, because they made the authentication?

Comment: Since I'm unable to move this discussion to a chat we'll just have to keep on going... I am also wondering if you have any thoughts on this. Twitter uses OAuth, and should Rails developers follow their path or what do you think. Do you think Twitter should maybe have chosen Devise?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Devise GEM, because there's no point of reinventing the wheel and Devise has lot of flexiblity and extensibility.

Have a look at the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise for the gem inclusion and you can view the HOW TO's at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks!:D I'm considering Sorcery though, and giving it a try now. I like how Ryan Bates considers its easiness, and how easy it is to use and such. Also I feel like Devise and Authlogic are the mainstream patterns, and I want to try something a little more down the line.
Not that Devise and Authlogic are bad in any means. :P